# В чем смысл предупреждения "C4996: '...': This function or variable may be unsafe"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пользуюсь Microsoft Visual Studio, и он выдаёт предупреждение С4996, например:

> `warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.`
>
> `warning C4996: 'fscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fscanf_s instead.`
>
> `warning C4996: 'chsize': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _chsize.`

Что за хрень и как с ней бороться?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft объявила ряд функций устаревшими (deprecated)/ Это связано с тем, что данные функции не проверяют возможности переполнения буфера. Например,

```
char str[5]; ... strcpy(str, "Hello World!");
```

в этом случае strcpy произведет запись за пределами выделенного буфера (Hello World! - это 13 char'ов (с завершающим 0), а не 5, что может привести к изменению значений других динамических переменных, затиранию информации на стеке - к трудно находимым ошибкам при выполнении программы... Для устранения этого недостатка были разработаны "безопасные" функции с суффиксом _s (fscanf_s)... Для отключения выдачи этих сообщений объявите макрос

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

или (в зависимости от версии заголовочных файлов), возможно,

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
```

перед включением заголовочных файлов стандартных библиотек.

Для отключения сообщения о "POSIX" можно использовать

```
 #define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
```

также можно попробовать

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
```

Comment: спасибо за информацию!