# Чтение из файла

Tags: c++

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка и как её ликвидировать
Код(c++):

```
FILE* fp; //кодировка (чтение файла)
int *str;
char symbol = ' ', kaka = ' ';
long long int size = 10;
long long int count = 1;
unsigned char ch;
long long int cho = 0;
long long int cc = 0;
long long int i = 0;
fp = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
if (!fp) throw"Файл  отсутствует\n";
do
{
kaka = (char)fgetc(fp);
cc++;
} 
while (!feof(fp));
size = cc;
fclose(fp);
fp = fopen("input1.txt", "rb");
do
{
    str = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)* cc);
    do
    {
    fread(&ch, 1, 1, fp);
        cho = ch;
        str[i] = cho;
        i++;
        cc--;
    } while (cc != 0);
} 
while (!feof(fp));
fclose(fp);
```

Ошибка: Ошибка  1   error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: Смените ОС. Обучение упростится.

Answer (score 1):

[В чем смысл предупреждения "C4996: '...': This function or variable may be unsafe"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/)

А способ определения длины файла - супер!