# Обращение функции к переменной типа char

Tags: c++

Необходимо написать параметры и тело функции `func`, так чтобы строка вывода программы выглядела следующим образом: `text 60`. Программа запускается, но вместо текста там просто набор символов а-ля:

> ННННННННННННННННээээЭЭЭЭН0щu?I

Что я сделала не так и как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
void func(int& a, char word[])
{
    word = "text";
    a = a*6;
}
int main()
{
    int value1 = 10;
    char* value2 = new char[16];
    func(value1, value2);
    cout << value2 << " " << value1 << "\n";
    delete value2;
    return 0;
}
```

Так же нужно найти ошибку в выделении памяти.

Comment: Для передачи и вывода текста в С++ следует использовать std::string http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для массивов символов не работает присваивание строковых литералов. Чтобы в такой массив записать какую-то строку, нужно использовать функцию `strcpy` из `string.h`:

```
void func(int& a, char word[])
{
    strcpy(word, "text");
    a = a*6;
}
```

Еще, лучше не называть переменные ничего не значащими именами `value1`, `value2`, а называть их согласно назначению.

Comment: Я понимаю, что лучше давать нормальные имена, но не я писала этот код, он всего лишь является тестом. И у меня выдает ошибку следующего вида, если я использую Ваш вариант :Error 1 error C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: Если это текст задания, тогда ладно. По поводу ошибки: Microsoft считает некоторые функции стандартной библиотеки небезопасными. В тексте ошибки прямо указано что делать: или использовать функцию `strcpy_s` (тогда еще нужно вторым параметром указать максимальное количество символов в целевой строке, у вас это 15), или отключить предупреждение.

Comment: @Darita, попробуйте удовлетворить систему тестирования, используя `strncpy()`

Comment: @insolor Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

Странное какое-то задание, неочевидное, и код более чем странный. Вероятно вы даже не понимаете, что делаете. А проблема в том, что `word` это не внешний массив, который можно изменить простым присваиванием, а указатель.

Т.е. нет никакой разницы между

```
void func(int& a, char word[])
```

и

```
void func(int& a, char* word)
```

Внутри функции же присваивается адрес локальному для функции указателю. 
Т.е. то, что снаружи функции `value2` фактически никак не меняется. Чтобы оно изменилось, нужно записать данные по указателю `word`, а не изменить сам указатель. Для строк это можно сделать так:

```
strcpy(word, "text");
```

Ну а ещё `delete value2;` следует заменить на `delete [] value2;`, т.к. выделяли память для массива, то и удалять надо как для массива.

Comment: Вы правы, я мало понимаю как нужно работать в данном случае с переменными char, поскольку мой опыт работы с ними до безобразия скуден. Я попробовала написать, как вы сказали, и ничего не вышло, разве что программа перестала запускаться. Задание само - разобраться в коде и написать тело функции func, чтобы оно выводило так, как сказано выше.

Comment: @Darita [всё работает](https://wandbox.org/permlink/efzrsWZoWyRX1F11).

Comment: У  меня же выдает ошибку Error 1 error C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: @Darita это уже совсем [другая история](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/26196/176217).

Comment: Ну это да. Спасибо за ответы

Comment: @Darita пожалуйста. Не забывайте голосовать за ответы и принимать наиболее подходящий. Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском!