# Нужна помощь, пишу код в VS C++. Выдает ошибку C4996. Раньше прекрасно работала функция strcpy, сейчас же требуют strcpy_s. Если что, я новичок

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class MyString
{
private:
    char* Buffer;

public:
    MyString(const char* InitialInput)
    {
        if (InitialInput != NULL)
        {
            Buffer = new char[strlen(InitialInput) + 1];
            strcpy(Buffer, InitialInput);
        }
        else
        {
            Buffer = NULL;
        }
    }

    ~MyString()
    {
        std::cout << "Invoking destructor, clearing up" << std::endl;
        if (Buffer != NULL)
        {
            delete [] Buffer;
        }
    }

    int GetLength()
    {
        return strlen(Buffer);
    }

    const char* GetString()
    {
        return Buffer;
    }
};


int main()
{
    MyString SayHello("Hello from String Class");
    std::cout << "String buffer in MyString is " << SayHello.GetLength();
    std::cout << " characters long" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Buffer contains: " << SayHello.GetString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [В чем смысл предупреждения "C4996: '...': This function or variable may be unsafe"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/26196)

Answer (score 1):

Ну вам же четко сказали, что делать!

> Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Вариант первый —

```
        Buffer = new char[strlen(InitialInput) + 1];
        strcpy_s(Buffer, strlen(InitialInput)+1, InitialInput);
    }
```

Вариант второй —

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
```

Что именно вам было непонятно в сообщении об ошибке?

Comment: Зачем отвечать на такие вопросы?!